# How to publish a website with sql local db database to azure using visual studio 2013

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have my website up and running on local server I want to published it to azure. I searched a lot but unable to do so however succeeded in publishing without database.Can any one provide a step by step guide how to published to azure and what tools to download from azure management portal.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure and let us know if you need more help. You will just need Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: When create website by clicking create button it says that there are some errors remaining before u create a website.

Comment: Check the output pane of Visual Studio for more information

Comment: Some people said I can't use local db there is it true?

Comment: Yes, localdb is one of the execution modes in SQL Express and comes with default MVC template on VS 2013, this is a file based storage so works only with local machines mostly used while development and testing. This should be appropriately replaced with SQL Database or any other SQL connections during deployment. This is taken care by the publish engine on VS if configured properly. But this would only generate a warning message not an error as far as I know. In any such case output pane will have details.

Comment: I have to create database on azure and then setup connection of that database to my website?

Comment: Yes. As mentioned in my link connect to the database in the settings section while publishing. This is a one time activity, from next time the database connection strings are automatically switched when deployed.

Comment: local db is so convenient.  It's nice to think of your data being all encapsulated in one file without a ridiculous amount of configuration to access and deploy it along with the rest of your application.  For simple job-based scenarios it really is quite perfect (you can easily save/backup and restore data/.mdf files, for instance), and it would be great to see this scenario supported.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `localdb` with Azure Websites.

That said, you can use `localdb` for development, but change the connection string on deployment to use some other database, such as SQL Azure (see http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/07/17/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/)