# Publishing Winforms app that uses EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, code-first, publishing

I've searched this forum and the closest thing I can find to my problem is this: [EF Codefirst Winforms app - Connection string problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557230/ef-codefirst-winforms-app-connection-string-problems). That thread is unresolved so I hope i have better luck.

I have a Winforms app written in C# using Visual Studio 2013. The app (via EF Code First) creates a database if it doesn't already exist. It works as planned when ran from the Dev environment. However, when I create the installer (Right click --> Publish) and installed version on same machine throws the following error when it first attempts to create the DB:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expansion of |DataDirectory| failed while processing the connection string. Ensure that |DataDirectory| is set to a valid fully-qualified path.
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.ExpandDataDirectory(String path)
  at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetOrGenerateDatabaseNameAndGetFileNames(SqlConnection sqlConnection, String& databaseName, String& dataFileName, String& logFileName)
  at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
  at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
  at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
  at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
  at ImageEditor.WinForms.frmCropProfile.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Apparently, there is something I am missing. I admit, I'm not exactly sure what EF is doing behind the scenes but I guess I need to figure it out. But doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose? I can see the database it creates in the SQL Server Object Explorer ((localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB). Like the other thread I can find no connection string in any of the XML config files.

This code:

```
MessageBox.Show(_context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString.ToString());
```

Returns this:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;InitialCatalog=MyApp.MyAppDataEntities;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.