# When I publish from Visual Studio to Azure my database doesn't get published and so any functionality requiring that breaks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure

I have a C# college project coming up that requires me to build and deploy a C# .NET MVC web application. I have fully built it and it works fine locally but when I deploy to Azure it sends everything except the database.

When I am publishing my project through VS I make sure to copy the connection string from my database in, I test the connection to make sure everything works fine, but when I get to the final 'Publish' screen down at the bottom it does not have any database selected to publish. That is unless I tick the box 'Execute code first migrations' and then one will be there at this final screen, however it doesn't seem to actually get published.

It's really frustrating me at this point that I have everything make and working just fine locally however this hiccup could cost me the project. Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Many words but very few information to help you.  What kind of database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I seems that you need to publish the Azure site with local database. If it is that case, I recommond you to use the Azure SQL database. You could refer to azure official document [Build an ASP.NET app in Azure with SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase) to get detail steps.

Related link:

[How to publish a website with sql local db database to azure using visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376520/how-to-publish-a-website-with-sql-local-db-database-to-azure-using-visual-studio)